# Como contar a quantidade de itens separados por vírgula no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um campo em uma tabela com dados separados por vírgula: `condicao_pagamento: 20,25,35,45,50`.

Como faço para contar a quantidade de itens separados por vírgula utilizando apenas MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se é isto que pretende:

```
LENGTH(fooCommaDelimColumn) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fooCommaDelimColumn, ',', ''))
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7020024/3792998)

Comment: Eu havia encontrado este código há alguns dias, ele funciona quase que perfeitamente. Porém, achei que essa não fosse a forma correta de se contar a quantidade de itens separados por virgula. Você sabe se existe algum comando parecido com `FIND_IN_SET` ou `IN`, específico para contar itens separados por virgula, sem a necessidade de realizar esse "calculo"?

Comment: Não conheço, e pela pesquisa que fiz não encontrei nenhuma função que conseguisse fazer isso...